# Keeping NuGet packages in Visual Studio projects up to date

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I find that when I start a new project, specifically MVC 5, using the One ASP.NET wizard/templates, I find myself running a few NuGet commands to update especially the script packages, e.g. jQuery, jQuery validate, and bootstrap. I would like to have all new projects I start have up to date versions of these, and other, packages.

I see two candidate solutions here, but the first, the idea of updating the project template, seems much less feasible, given the complexities apparent in One ASP.NET projects, and the rumoured dropping of T4 in MVC 6. My remaining solution is to automate the process of updating these NuGet packages. Is there a means built-in to NuGet? Or will I just be scripting a bunch of `Install-Package` cmdlets, and where would I place this script?

Comment: `Update-Package`? Or are there some that you don't want updating?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765802/nuget-spec-dependencies-get-latest-version/26340666#26340666