# Build C# standard project with the latest versions of the nuget references

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, version, .net-standard

When using new C# projects we don't have packages.config files. The dependencies are specified inside the *.proj file, something like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="XYZ.Definitions" Version="1.0.0-CI-20181010-102209" />
    <PackageReference Include="XYZ.Definitions.Common" Version="1.0.0-CI-20181010-102209" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**How can I specify that I always want to build with the latest versions available of my references?**

I was thinking something like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="XYZ.Definitions" Version="latest" />
    <PackageReference Include="XYZ.Definitions.Common" Version="latest" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I dont know if this is even possible.
Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26340666/1499972) you can find a solution but in another context, that is using packages.config and nuget.config files.

Answer (score 1):

`*` will use the latest stable version available.

Solution:

```
<PackageReference Include="XYZ.Definitions" Version="*" />
```